# Should a favorite bookmark prompt the user to upvote?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, bookmark

I've encountered many questions that have been bookmarked but have no up votes. It seems reasonable that an individual wishing to keep tabs on a question would be of mind to vote up the question as well.

I'm not sure I'd like auto-upvoting from users who add a question to their favorites, but a friendly prompt to consider upvoting when the user chooses to bookmark the question seems reasonable. This would be similar to the prompt to provide feedback when flagging a question. Thoughts?

Also, it seems the bar for the `Favorite Question` badge is quite high at 25. Perhaps it would be more inline with the other tiered question badge categories to set the favorite question badges as follows:

- `Favorite Question`: Question favorited by 10 users (changed from silver to bronze)
- `Insightful Question`: Question favorited by 25 users (new name, but current silver badge)
- `Stellar Question`: Question favorited by 100 users (current name and badge)

In short, I think these changes would reward and encourage good questions and would add consistency regarding question badges and feedback to the questioners.

Comment: I agree with the second half of your post (badge tiers) purely for consistency. However, I'm not so sure about the first half: sometimes favoriting is used merely to keep a repository of useful questions to refer to in answers (since SE search isn't the best) or sometimes a question is simply *so bad* that you want to keep it as a favorite to look back on. I also find that many new users favorite their own question (which may be why you've seen lots of favorited-but-not-upvoted questions) because they are not aware that they are notified of all new activity on their posts automatically.

Comment: I sometimes favorite questions that I think are awful, but am not 100% sure of myself, and just want to see how it gets answered and/or downvoted. I'm not favoriting because I approve, but just tagging it for future reference. I'm not sure if there is any other better way to track a question(?)

Comment: Good points, I guess given both your examples the proposed prompt could encourage voting up or down.

Comment: I *mostly* star a post to keep tabs on it; if a user keeps vandalising the post for example. That's because new events cause your Favourites tab to be highlighted. I'd strongly object to auto-upvotes or even reminders. Starring has uses beyond 'liking' a post.

Comment: Got it, I agree the prompt is a bad idea, but what about the badges?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I often favorite bad question to keep track of them in terms of close and delete votes.

Comment: Same here. Definitely don't need to be prompted to upvote everything I star.