# Observing a question

Tags: feature-request

I'm currently watching some tags for a new questions which I may answer. Most of the questions are very easy to answer but some not. For me it's very good way to learn something new, because if I cannot answer the question it's likely that I will learn something from the answer.

I would like to see an option to watch a question for changes/answers. Currently I'm adding the question to my Google Calendar and check it every 2-3 days for changes. I think it could be handled better e.g. with a friendly notification about new answer in the question I'm interested in.

Does anyone miss this option in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *already do this*. You have two options:

- Star the question. Your *Favorites* tab in your profile will list posts that have changed recently first, as well as show you the number of changes (new comments, answers, edited posts) as a number since you last looked at a question:

  [image: starring a question]
- Every question page has a RSS feed; look for the *question feed* in the sidebar, bottom.

  [image: question RSS feed link]

Comment: I know about the RSS, but it's too much work if you are using eg. feedly to add and remove the feed, but I didn't know that starring the question will notify me about new answers. Thanks!

Comment: While the "favorite" feature can be used this way, it seems overloaded. There is a set of badges for the poster depending on how many people favorited the question. Which suggests that it should only be used for really awesome questions. But in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262552/should-a-favorite-bookmark-prompt-the-user-to-upvote, some people suggested that they use it to bookmark really bad questions they want to observe. If enough people do that, somebody could get a "Stellar Question" gold badge for posting the worst question ever.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: But noone does that. Yes, power users use starring to track trainwrecks of questions. To make sure that they are deleted, or to monitor a post for vandalism, etc. But *not that many people do*; I've **never** seen 25 people star a bad question to earn the asker a badge. Bad questions are closed, deleted, cleaned out way before that would ever happen.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: in the meantime, starring explicitly supports this usecase; to monitor questions. That is *exactly why it is there*, to monitor and to group, something browser bookmarks cannot give you.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: if there ever is a problem with handing out the badges to questions that don't deserve it, it is easy enough to expand the criteria for those; say only open questions with a positive score can earn you those.

Comment: Yes, it might very well be a hypothetical problem. Is the favorite "score" also used for ranking questions in tabs/searches? I think it would be nice to have a simple bookmark feature that is just for myself, and doesn't influence any data. I know, I know, post it as a feature request. :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi: no, starring is not used in relevancy ranking or boosting search, *except* when you specifically ask the search to limit results to *posts you have starred*.