# Serial upvoting scheme

Tags: discussion, voting

Recently I stumbled upon a question which is very trivial, and found that within 20 views the question received 4 upvotes and was favorited.

I cannot imagine that any self-respecting user would upvote such a tedious question so I began to wonder, is there any evidence that people will have multiple accounts and upvote their trivial questions to make them seem worthwhile?

Maybe it's a group of programmers or Programming 101 students huddled in a room that just upvote each others posts?

Maybe it's just a natural flock of fresh programmers that do see value in the question?

Maybe SO has elevated my cynical-ness above the average threshold so now I am suspicious of everything?

Comment: _"Maybe it's just a flock of fresh programmers that do see value in the question?"_ These are called _voting monkeys_ and don't necessarily need to participate in a voting-ring.

Comment: This appears to be an invitation to downvote some unsuspecting user without any evidence to support it. If you believe there's an issue flag the post and explain it to a mod. They're more likely to be able to deal with it 'cause they can confirm whether or not your suspicions are true. Don't call for a witch hunt on meta.

Comment: Maybe Tim found his keys.

Comment: @Ben I certainly did not post with your accused reason in mind. It feels like I see this weekly but maybe that's because I check the PHP questions which are notoriously popular with new developers and worse yet, foreign developers.

Comment: This really should have been a custom flag as Undo states. I removed the link from your question in an edit because aside from idle suspicion there is nothing concrete and it is unfair to simply pile downvotes from here on to that post without fair reason.

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry, definitely did not mean to cause any issues for the asker of that question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - In all fairness, I can see where the suspicion would arise from, and have in the past flagged posts in this similar scenario as well.

Comment: @TravisJ Glad I'm not going crazy. Going forward I'll certainly make sure to heed the suggestions provided here. Thank you

Comment: "... was favorited" Do not assume that the yellow star/number mean anything positive. Plenty of people use it to track bad questions. Example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262552

Comment: @AndrewMedico is most likely correct. I frequently favorite questions that should be closed or downvoted when I run out of votes for the day, so that when a new day arrives I can revisit them (at which point I unfavorite them).

Answer (score 12):

I can see why you'd be suspicious of that. Flag the post with an "other" flag and explain your concerns.

In the future, it's better to go straight to flagging the post and bypass meta completely.

Comment: I did put a flag on it but I wanted to see if there was anything in meta about it. I cannot find anything identical to what I am suspecting so I thought maybe I stumbled upon a new phenomena and wanted to bring attention to it faster than a flagging it and explaining this in the Other field.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus And a mod is *specifically* telling you not to do that, and that these types of issues are best handled privately.

Comment: No worries, this is something that happens somewhat often.

Comment: @Servy thanks, I will certainly keep that in mind.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The problem with bringing something like this to meta is that you get a "trail by mob"-effect. Sure, many might be guilty of whatever they're accused of, but some will be innocent. Adding to that, the guilty won't even know that she's being accused of anything (you don't get a notification if a meta thread is posted about you), and if she does become aware of it, she now somehow has to prove her innocence. Plus, none of us have the tools to *conclusively* prove anything. Only mods do. So the best anyone can really do is shrug and say "yeah, that looks suspicious", but little more..

Answer (score 7):

It is not likely to be what you think it is, the voting fits a different pattern that's been increasingly a problem.  The question was reviewed in no less then *three* review queues.  It got the upvotes while traveling the queues.

It first ended up in the Triage review queue, co-incides with the 1st upvote. Then it entered the First Posts review queue, that landed it 3 more upvotes.  The question was then edited and that made it end up in the Edit review queue.  No upvotes there, the edit was quickly approved.  Two more sympathy upvotes after you exposed it in meta.

Only one reviewer is identified by name, the rest only upvoted.  That reviewer does not know anything about [php].  Which is in general a major source of trouble with these review queues, they are not usually done by anybody that knows anything about the [tag] subject so you cannot assume the review ever vets the question on technical content.  All the questioner has to do is format the question well enough and keep the content readable to get the thumbs up, makes it stand out from the usual dreck that the reviewers have to plow through.

Comment: There is an additional problem with that you cannot filter reviews (except close vote reviews) by tags effectively.

Comment: Nice sleuthing! I did not even consider that could be the source of this type of behavior.